# Creating mock instances of GIDGoogleUser

Tags: ios, swift, google-signin, xctest

I'm writing some Unit Tests and I need to create a mock instance of GIDGoogleUser to make sure my API returns a correct instance of my model User class which is subset of the fields in GIDGoogleUser.

Since GIDGoogleUser does not expose an initializer, and all it's properties are read only, I can't create a mock instance and inject it in to my converter. Is there any way I can do this?

For simplicity, this is what I'm doing:

```
struct User {
  let name: String

  init(googleUser: GIDGoogleUser) {
    name = googleUser.profile.name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you can't mock `GIDGoogleUser`. Here is a mock of `GIDGoogleUser` I made just now:

First, declare the protocols that `GIDGoogleUser` and `GIDProfileData` will conform to, as well as our mocks we'll make in a bit:

```swift
protocol GoogleUserProtocol {
    associatedtype Profile: ProfileDataProtocol
    var profile: Profile! { get }
}

protocol ProfileDataProtocol {
    var name: String! { get }
}
```

Then, have `GIDGoogleUser` and `GIDProfileData` conform to these protocols:

```swift
extension GIDGoogleUser: GoogleUserProtocol {}
extension GIDProfileData: ProfileDataProtocol {}
```

Then, create our mock classes (or structs as I opted for in this case), and have them conform to the above protocols:

```swift
struct MockGoogleUser: GoogleUserProtocol {
    let profile: MockProfileData!
}

struct MockProfileData: ProfileDataProtocol {
    let name: String!
}
```

Finally, adjust `User`'s initializer to take not a `GIDGoogleUser`, but instead anything that conforms to `GoogleUserProtocol`:

```swift
struct User {
    let name: String

    init<G>(googleUser: G) where G: GoogleUserProtocol {
        name = googleUser.profile.name
    }
}
```

This will let you create mock Google User instances and inject them into your `User`, like so:

```swift
let mockProfileData = MockProfileData(name: "Mock User Name")
let mockGoogleUser = MockGoogleUser(profile: mockProfileData)

let mockUser = User(googleUser: mockGoogleUser)

print(mockUser.name) // prints "Mock User Name"
```

And you can of course still init your `User` with "real" Google User objects too:

```swift
let realGoogleUser: GIDGoogleUser = ... // get a GIDGoogleUser after signing in

let realUser = User(googleUser: realGoogleUser)

print(realUser.name) // prints whatever the real GIDGoogleUser's name is
```